# Removing registry values with Qt Installer Framework

Tags: qt, qt5, qt-installer

Is there a way to remove Windows registry values when installing (and/or uninstalling) an application using the Qt Installer Framework?

I've tried the following as an installation script within a package:

```
function Component()
{
}

Component.prototype.createOperations = function()
{
    component.createOperations();

    if (systemInfo.productType === "windows") {
        component.addElevatedOperation("Execute", "cmd.exe", "/C", "reg delete \"HKEY_CURRENT_USER\\Software\\<company name>\\<appName>\"", "/f")
    }
}
```

During installation I get the following error:

```
Error during installation process (com.<companyName>.<appName>):
Execution failed (Unexpected exit code: 1) "cmd.exe "/C reg delete "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\<company name>\<appName>" /f"
```

(Note: our company name has a space in it, that's why I'm using quotation marks in the command).

**Qt Installer Framework**: 4.0
**Qt**: 5.15.2
**Compiler**: msvc2019 x64